# after creating a react app npm start doesnt work. No error message given

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

Im new to react and am having some trouble setting up a new app. I have followed the tutorial here.
https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html. However when i go to start npm it doesnt start and I get no error. Just put back into the console.

I had created a few apps before this started happening with no problem now when i go to start these i have the same issue.

I have updated and installed to most recent builds

Is there an error log file anywhere I can access? or can I log one to a .txt file as I run npm start

I get nothing unusual while creating.
    $ npx create-react-app seatracker

```
Creating a new React app in C:\react_tutorial_app\nnew\seatracker.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

+ react@16.12.0
+ react-dom@16.12.0
+ react-scripts@3.2.0
added 1480 packages from 694 contributors and audited 904937 packages in 89.688s
found 0 vulnerabilities


Initialized a git repository.

Success! Created seatracker at C:\react_tutorial_app\nnew\seatracker
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd seatracker
  npm start

Happy hacking!
```

and when starting npm no indication of what may be wrong

```
R@DESKTOP-ILPL80A MINGW64 /c/react_tutorial_app/nnew/seatracker (master)
$ npm start

R@DESKTOP-ILPL80A MINGW64 /c/react_tutorial_app/nnew/seatracker (master)
```

nothing i can see unusual in the json file

```
   {
  "name": "seatracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: which version are you using? `npm -v`

Comment: I'm using 6.13.1

Comment: hm. does the same happen in default Windows Command Prompt?

Comment: Yep same thing happens in CMD, Powershell and Git Bash

Answer (score 1):

One of the causes for this problem might be disabling npm installation scripts (for security reason) => check if they are disabled:

```
npm config get ignore-scripts
```

Current version of `create-react-app` needs to execute some stuff, so if the above is `true`, I would recommend:

```
npm config set ignore-scripts false
npx create-react-app seatracker
npm config set ignore-scripts true
cd seatracker
npm start
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used npx in a while. Try with `npm i create-react-app` and create app with `create-react-app myapp` and after that run app with `npm start`. Tell if that works.

Comment: Can you try reinstall Node?

Answer (score -1):

Try `cd seatracker` first and `npm start` after. 
Believe me.

Comment: I was already in the working directory (with package.json etc..) . Same result